# Performance of using asynchronous tasks to check for numbers in Excel

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, asynchronous

I made simple validation method which checks if data in cells are number or not.

```
public async void checkNumberMethod(Excel.Range numericRange,  bool isCompulsary)
{
    int errorCnt = await checkNumberAsync( numericRange,  colTable,  isCompulsary);

}

private Task<int> checkNumberAsync(Excel.Range numericRange,  bool isCompulsary)
{

    return Task.Run<int>(() => checkNumber(numericRange,isCompulsary));
}

private int checkNumber(Excel.Range numericRange,  bool isCompulsary)
{
    if (isCompulsary == true)
    {
        foreach(Excel.Range item in numericRange)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(Excel.Range item in numericRange)
        {
             //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And call this method,

```
checkNumberMethod(numericRange, true);                 
checkNumberMethod(numericRange,  false);
```

But this is much slower than just call

```
checkNumber( numericRange,  true);
checkNumber( numericRange,  false);
```

Task is not always quicker?
If you give me any idea, I will appreciate very much.

Comment: Why would running an async method which awaits on a method that runs a Task that calls a final method would ever be faster than just calling the final method? This would *only* be faster (and just "may" be faster, depending on many conditions) if you create many tasks in parallel (or it'll allow you to run other code while the task is completing). Just one task will never be faster, since there's a lot of overhead just to call and wait for that final method to execute. You are basically creating a task to be run synchronously.

Comment: How many times is checkmethodasyn being called?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Task` is not always quickier than directly call the method. Let's dive in your code, and see, whats happening here:

You are calling the `checkNumberMethod` and start the inner method asynchroniously, after that .NET creates and machine state, which will be loaded after your task finishes. Inside there is an another one `Task`, which takes resources to run in the background in the thread pool.

So, `async/await` will **reduce** the speed of the your program if your work is short - overhead of the state machine creation and task background running is a constant value, which will be always in your program, even for instant method.

Answer (score 2):

No, a task is not quicker. It does not have anything to do with performance, it just means it's run in parallel. If you are waiting for it to finish, you have gained nothing from the parallelism but overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This is one major reason I don't like the way COM does threading for you. In this case, `Excel.Range` is an STA COM component, which will do automatic thread marshaling in an attempt to "help".

STA components will synchronize back to their owning thread every time you try to use them from another context. So, in this case, your code is sending some work to a background thread, and then that background work is constantly turning around and synchronizing to the UI thread behind your back.

You can separate out the STA stuff from the "real work", e.g., by copying whatever `Range` data you need into a regular `List<T>` before invoking `Task.Run`. However, you'd still have to consider the issues the other answers here have mentioned: namely, if you only have a small amount of work, pushing it to a background thread would only add overhead.

As a final note, keep in mind that "asynchronous" does not mean "faster". *Asynchrony* is just a way of doing multiple things without using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others using a `Task` is not necessarily quicker, but on the client it can allow you to push work into the background and keep your client responsive. Using the TPL you can also process results in parallel which can be much quicker. E.g.

```
numericRange.AsParallel().ForAll(() => /* check each number*/);
```

PLINQ's `AsParallel` as well as `Parallel.ForEach` allow you to process you data in parallel. There are some blogs on the subject [here](http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/).

When you are invoking an asynchronous IO operation `Tasks` are even better because they allow you to free up the current thread to do other work.